# servlet http status 404 - not found

Tags: eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

How to solve **Http Status 404 - not found** in servlet application? The description for this error is

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I am using Tomcat 7 and Eclipse for development. I am using Mac OS. Here's the link for the screenshot of the error.

[image: Servlet Application]]

Comment: Is your web.xml configured properly? Hard to help without context

Comment: yes my web.xml is configured properly. I am just retrieving data from index.html file and storing it in database. Heres the web.xml `<display-name>Servlet_Application_Example</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>student</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.employee.Employee</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>student</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: Do you have an index.jsp file?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Now it works fine. I had index.html file instead of index.jsp file.